# Join two files on two common fields

Tags: text-processing, files, awk

I have two files

`file1.txt`

```
78Z|033333157|0000001|PERD1|2150421|D|0507020|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|PERD0|2160208|A|1900460|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|RSAB1|2150421|D|0507070|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|RSAB0|2160208|A|1900460|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|ANT37|2141023|D|1245260|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|ANT36|2150422|D|1518490|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|ANT28|2150321|D|0502090|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|ANT27|2150122|D|0501450|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|ANT26|2141222|D|1637460|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|ANT10|2160208|A|1900460|3333333311
78Z|033333157|0000001|ABS10|2151221|D|1223390|3333333311
78Z|696931836|0000001|PERD0|2160203|A|1114450|2222222222
78Z|696931836|0000001|RSAB0|2160203|A|1114450|2222222222
78Z|696931836|0000001|ANT09|2160203|A|1114450|2222222222
78Z|010041586|0000001|PERD0|2160119|A|1835100|3333333333
78Z|010041586|0000001|RSAB0|2160119|A|1835100|3333333333
78Z|010041586|0000001|ANT33|2160119|A|1835100|3333333333
78Z|011512345|0000001|PERD0|2151213|A|1413550|4444444444
78Z|011512345|0000001|RSAB0|2151213|A|1413550|4444444444
78Z|011512345|0000001|ANT32|2160219|A|0319230|4444444444
78Z|011512345|0000001|ANT09|2160218|D|0319230|4444444444
78Z|011512345|0000001|ANT07|2150729|D|1508230|4444444444
78Z|011512345|0000001|ANT06|2141013|D|1208190|4444444444
78Z|011512345|0000001|ABB06|2131224|D|1857030|4444444444
78Z|012344052|0000001|PERD0|2160203|A|1219570|5555555555
78Z|012344052|0000001|ANT50|2160203|A|1219570|5555555555
78Z|099999999|0000001|PERD0|2151214|A|1512460|6666666666
78Z|099999999|0000001|RSAB0|2151214|A|1512460|6666666666
78Z|099999999|0000001|ANT32|2160219|A|0319000|6666666666
78Z|099999999|0000001|ANT09|2160218|D|0319000|6666666666
78Z|099999999|0000001|ABS10|2150615|D|0125350|6666666666
```

`file2.txt`

```
3333333311|ANT10
2222222222|ANT09
5555555555|ANT50
3333333333|ANT33
6666666666|ANT32
4444444444|ANT09
```

I need a create new file with the lines matched by fourth and eighth column of the `file1.txt` with second and first column of the `file2.txt`

The result must be (the order is not important)

`file3.txt`

```
78Z|033333157|0000001|ANT10|2160208|A|1900460|3333333311
78Z|696931836|0000001|ANT09|2160203|A|1114450|2222222222
78Z|012344052|0000001|ANT50|2160203|A|1219570|5555555555
78Z|010041586|0000001|ANT33|2160119|A|1835100|3333333333
78Z|099999999|0000001|ANT32|2160219|A|0319000|6666666666
78Z|011512345|0000001|ANT09|2160218|D|0319230|4444444444
```

Comment: Please improve your question. You don't *ask* something. And please specify that you want and answer with `awk`: apart from the "awk" tag you used, we don't see that...

Comment: @Totor - the post says _"I  need to create new file with the lines...."_ and _"the result must be..."_ Isn't that enough ?  And why should OP specify the answer needs to be `awk` ?

Comment: @don_crissti if the OP uses the tag "awk" on it's question, I expect to discover why when I read the question, but here, I don't know. I think this question can be improved with a tiny effort. Just saying this because, as you may have noticed, there is a close vote on it "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @Totor - no. It's perfectly fine - _there are thousands of questions_ tagged awk or sed or perl and the authors do NOT explain why - most times because they don't even know which tool is right one. Also, I'm not sure what exactly is unclear, especially after all the edits - it was pretty clear to me even before the edits.

Comment: Thank you for your all comments, I forget specifc tag of the question, the answerd must be in awk, I working with awk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{e[$2$1]=1;next};e[$4$8]' file2.txt file1.txt
```

First read *file2* and set array `e[field2+field1]` then *file1* and print if `e[field4+field8]` is set.

Or turn the fields around:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{e[$1$2]=1;next};e[$8$4]' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @Sukminder, the instruction works correctly!!!!

Answer (score 4):

The question is tagged [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), but I think its worth noting that you don't *have* to use `awk` to do this.  The coreutils have a `join` utility which is useful for this sort of thing, though with your data it is a bit cumbersome.

I'm going to assume your shell is bash and GNU coreutils.  This can be done with other flavours, but will probably need more pre-/post-processing of your data.

Without further ado:

```bash
join -t"|" -14 -22 -o"$(echo 1.{1..8} 2.1)" \
  <(sort -t"|" -k4 file1.txt) \
  <(sort -t"|" -k2 file2.txt) \
  | grep -Po ".*([\d]+)(?=\|\1$)"
```

`join` takes two input files and joins them on the fields passed with the `-1` and `-2` parameters.  `-t` indicates a custom field separator in the input files.  `join` requires that the input files are sorted on the fields being joined, so the two input files are sorted within process substitutions before being passed to `join`.  The `-o` parameter specifies how fields are to be output.  By default it is join field, followed by non-join fields of file1, followed by non-join fields of file2, so we need to specify we want all fields of file 1 in order, followed by field 1 of file 2.

You also require the join to be on field 8 of file1 and field 1 of file1.  This is simply implemented here by grepping for lines when the join output fields 8 and 9 are the same.  Using a regexp lookahead with `grep -Po` allows us to do this and effectively delete field 9 to give the required output.  The output is:

```bash
78Z|696931836|0000001|ANT09|2160203|A|1114450|2222222222
78Z|011512345|0000001|ANT09|2160218|D|0319230|4444444444
78Z|033333157|0000001|ANT10|2160208|A|1900460|3333333311
78Z|099999999|0000001|ANT32|2160219|A|0319000|6666666666
78Z|010041586|0000001|ANT33|2160119|A|1835100|3333333333
78Z|012344052|0000001|ANT50|2160203|A|1219570|5555555555
```

Comment: In case it's useful to anyone, here's a portable alternative to the grep component: `sed -n 's/\([^|]\{1,\}\)|\1$/\1/p'`

Comment: @Digital Trauma Thanks for answer, however I request de code in awk, your code is works perfect, use join is another solution for my request.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler, assuming that in file2 it is not allowed to give the same first field twice:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR == NR { key[$1] = $2; next } $8 in key && key[$8] == $4' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|"}
     FNR == NR { key[$2 $1]=NR }
     FNR > NR { k=$3 $8 ;if (k in key)  print ;} ' file2.txt file1.txt
```

where

- `BEGIN { FS="|"}` tell aw to use `|` as separator (you can use `-F\|` on command line )
- `FNR == NR { key[$2 $1]=NR }` remember key from file (when in file2.txt)
- `FNR > NR { k=$4 $8 ;if (k in key)  print ;}` if key in hash list, print it

Edit: you mention third filed and join on fourth.

Comment: FYI, since you never use the values stored in the `key` array, you can just omit the value assignment.  `key[$2 $1]` will create the array element just as well and is a lot tidier.